# How to display a YT video in MAUI?

Tags: c#, android, video, maui

I am trying to display a video in my app. I would like to display it from YT.

I am creating `MediaElement` in xaml from:

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
<toolkit:MediaElement Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="mediaElement"
        ShouldAutoPlay="True"
        ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True"
        Margin="10,10,10,10"/>
```

But I am not able to put url to my video. I was able to show video from other websites, but not from YT. I have read that it is impossible to display it directly by providing a link from YT. And I don't have much of an idea how to get around it. I tried using external libraries to extract the stream, but it failed.

I tried to create a WebView control, but in it I was only able to display the entire page from yt, not the video.

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,10"/>.
```

Comment: YT can't make any money if they let you display their videos for free

Comment: @Jason I thought I saw the apps had a yt video. With the button "watch on YT". I was going to add my video, in which I talk about my app, and it seemed logical to display it directly from YT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: use WebView and youtube url with embed

```
<WebView Source="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<yourMovieId>"/>
```